# Python testing tool for complex multiprocessing & multithreading fuzzy testing

Tags: python, multithreading, testing, multiprocessing, pytest

**The background:**

My team needs to test a distributed protocol implementation (Eg: RAFT algorithm), the implementation is based on a rpc layer(Eg: grpc), We have implemented a mocked rpc layer based on utils provided by the `multiprocessing` library, and we may perform operations such as reorder, drop, delay to simulate real network environments. The `mock` library is used to inject simulated functions. We spawn subprocesses as agents in the distributed protocol.

**Current testing harness:**

We are using pytest as our major framework, pytest is great for single thread testing, but not appropriate for this scenario, because exceptions cannot be caught in threads / processes spawned by the tested function. We have tried to create runners which can capture exceptions and send exceptions back and reraise:

```
result = [None, None, None]
    finished = [False, False, False]
    while not all(finished):
        for p, pi, i in zip(procs, proc_pipes, [0, 1, 2]):
            if pi.poll(timeout=1e-3):
                status, r = pi.recv()
                if status:
                    finished[i] = True
                    result[i] = r
                else:
                    raise r
    return result
```

But this method is only sufficient for capturing exceptions thrown by agent processes created during testing (Eg: created with `pytest.fixture`), and cannot monitor exceptions thrown in background threads spawned in the algorithm.

**Some requirements:**

If there is a tool other than pytest designed specifically for testing distributed program, that would be the best.

If there doesn't exist such a tool, then we wish to find a pytest plugin which can monitor threads & processes spawned during test execution, it would be best if it comes with a filter function to ignore some exceptions.

If that is not possible, then it should terminate the test immediately if any exception is thrown in any threads/processes, we will use other logging tools to capture the execution process.

Thanks for your generous help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [pytest-reraise](https://github.com/bjoluc/pytest-reraise) can help you here?
It provides a context manager fixture to capture exceptions from other threads and fail the test case when an exception was captured. Here's a minimal example test case that would fail and provide details on the assertion error:

```py
from threading import Thread

def test_assert(reraise):

    def run():
        with reraise:
            assert False

    Thread(target=run).start()
```